# VS Code extension to highlight duplicates css properties

Tags: css, visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting

Any VS Code extension to highlight duplicate css properties? 
e.g

```
.test {
  font-size: 14px;
  ...
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There are built-in settings which will flag duplicate properties :

> // Do not use duplicate style definitions.

```
 "css.lint.duplicateProperties": "ignore",
```

> // Do not use duplicate style definitions.

```
 "less.lint.duplicateProperties": "ignore",
```

> // Do not use duplicate style definitions.

```
"scss.lint.duplicateProperties": "ignore"
```

Options are `ignore`, `warning` and `error`.  Default is "`ignore`".

Comment: this is nice, do you know a way to do the same with styled components please? shouldn't be that difficult as it uses SASS/SCSS notation, but enabling scss.lint.duplicateProperties doesn't trap the duplications :(